# Check for Duplicate Values in Each Child in XML via LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm new to using linq in particular linq to xml and am having trouble trying to iterate through the results. My xml document has multiple nodes of the same name nested in a single parent node.

Sample XML is :

```
<commercial>
   <listingAgent>1</listingAgent>
   <listingAgent>2</listingAgent>
   <listingAgent>1</listingAgent>
</commercial>  
<commercial>
   <listingAgent>1</listingAgent>
   <listingAgent>2</listingAgent>
   <listingAgent>3</listingAgent>
</commercial>
```

So for each commercial tag there should be unique listing agent values. If not i need to raise an error.

The real XML is extremely complicated and these tags are nowhere near root. So i need to traverse to these and then search for duplciates

I tried the following code

```
foreach (XElement e in root.Descendants("listingAgent"))
{
   listerror.Add(e.Value);
}

if(listerror.Count != listerror.Distinct().Count()) 
     Then show error
```

But i need this looping to be done for each commercial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, select all the commercial nodes, then for each node you can get the list of agents values using a `Select`, this way you will get a list of list, and finally you can apply the same condition you try before, but now for each list of agents:

```
var result= xdoc.Descendants("commercial")
                .Select(c=>c.Descendants("listingAgent").Select(e=>e.Value));
if(result.Any(e=>e.Count()!= e.Distinct().Count())
{
  //error
}
```

Comment: Hi.. sorry for not being clear in my question but listingAgent is not a direct child of commercial. Will this still work?

Comment: Well if, agents is inside of commercial, just use `Descendants` instead `Elements` method

Comment: Hey thanks for this.. If I may ask another related question.. How to identify if tag is duplicate? Not just the value but also the tag name? Example how to throw an error if there are more than one listingagent tags inside a Commercial tag??

Comment: The best way to detect duplicates elements is using a group by. `XElement` has a property called `Name`, group by that property

Comment: Can you help with a query? I am new to XML

Comment: @BhumikaSanghvi, please, create a new question with the new issue, what you need now is different what you ask in your original question. Let me know by a comment when you publish it